# Update data of forgeign key model in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, orm

I have a two model

```
class LabReportRelation(models.Model):
    labReportId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    collectedSampleId = models.ForeignKey(CollectedSample, null=True)
    ....
    ....
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'labReportRelation'

class CollectedSample(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, max_length=5)
    collectionTime = models.DateTimeField()
    ....
    ....
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'collectedSample'
```

I want to update the 'collectionTime' of `CollectedSample` model related to the 'labereportId'

my current query is:

```
LabReportRelation.objects.filter(labReportId__in=labReportIdList)
         .prefetch_related('collectedSampleId')
         .update(
            collectedSampleId_collectionTime=updateTime
         )
```

But I am getting this error.

```
FieldDoesNotExist(u"labReportRelation has no field named 'collectedSampleId_collectionTime'",)
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
CollectedSample.objects.filter(labreportrelation__labReportId__in=labReportIdList).update(collectionTime=updateTime)
```

Assuming `labReportIdList` is a list.

Running the following (models are exactly as in OP):

```
import os

_module = os.path.split(os.path.dirname(__file__))[-1]
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "{}.settings".format(_module))
import django

django.setup()
from app.models import CollectedSample, LabReportRelation
from django.utils.timezone import now


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sample = CollectedSample.objects.create(collectionTime=now())
    report = LabReportRelation.objects.create(collectedSampleId=sample)
    print(f"Initial collection time: {sample.collectionTime} for sample {sample.id}")
    labReportIdList = [report.labReportId]
    updateTime = now()
    CollectedSample.objects.filter(labreportrelation__labReportId__in=labReportIdList).update(collectionTime=updateTime)
    sample = CollectedSample.objects.get(pk=sample.pk)
    print(f"Updated collection time: {sample.collectionTime} for sample {sample.id}")
```

Prints:

```
Initial collection time: 2019-02-23 07:51:10.578433+00:00 for sample 3
Updated collection time: 2019-02-23 07:51:10.735463+00:00 for sample 3
```

It follows the ForeignKey relation backwards, as explained in the official docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Answer (score 0):

Oh got it collectedSampleId is foreign key so you should use `select_related`

```
LabReportRelation.objects.filter(labReportId__in=labReportIdList)
     .select_related('collectedSampleId')
     .update(
        collectedSampleId__collectionTime=updateTime
     )
```

Comment: `FieldDoesNotExist(u"labReportRelation has no field named 'collectedSampleId__collectionTime'",)` Gettind same error I have tried.

Comment: `lab_report`  will return a list of the `LabReportRelation` so we can't directly update like `lab_report.collectedSampleId.................`.

Comment: @GAJESHPANIGRAHI  u should use `select_related` i updated the answer.

Comment: my bad use this `collectedSampleId__collectionTime=updateTime`

Comment: I have tried but still getting the same error. I think we are missing something.